# changing values of array elements in javascript functions

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

These are my three functions that I am using in javascript :

```
function postRequest()
{

    var xmlHttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { // For Mozilla, Safari, ...
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    { // For Internet Explorer
        var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttp.open('GET', 'effort.php', true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {       
            get_string(xmlHttp.responseText);
            dij();
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}


function get_string(str)
{
    get_integer = str.split(" ");
    for(var i=0;i<214;i++)
    {
        vertex_i[j] = get_integer[i]*1;
        j++;
    }

    j=0;
    for(var i=214;i<427;i++)
    {
        vertex_f[j] = get_integer[i]*1;
        j++;
    }
    j=0;;
    for(var i=427;i<517;i++)
    {
        x[j] = get_integer[i]*1;
        j++;
    }
    j=0;
    for(var i=517;i<607;i++)
    {
        y[j] = get_integer[i]*1;
        j++;
    }


    for(var m=0;m<90;m++)
    {
        for(var n=0;n<90;n++)
        {   
            L[m][n] = -1;           
        }
    }
    for(var m=0;m<212;m++)
    {
        x1 = x[vertex_i[m]];
        x2 = x[vertex_f[m]];

        y1 = y[vertex_i[m]];
        y2 = y[vertex_f[m]];
        L[vertex_i[m]][vertex_f[m]] = parseInt(find_dist(x1,x2,y1,y2)); 
    }

}


function point_it(event)
{
    postRequest();


}
```

namely :
`point_it(event)`,then `postRequest();` and finally `dij();`

In these functions I use the data in three globally defined arrays,the elements of whose are derived from the data sent by the server(get_string function).

if I call `dij()` function from within the `postRequest()` function(after the get_string function I am able to access the correct data within the arrays.

However if I call it immediately after the `postRequest()` function the value of elements in the array become equal to null.
I am unable to understand the proper reason for this and have tried several ways to get through but with no progress. 
CAn sm1 please help me out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`postRequest` fires an **asynchronous** request to the server. Calling a function directly after it doesnt mean that the request has finished and youve doen anything with the response data. It works inside `postRequest` because that where you actually handle processing the request and response.

if you want to do this all from within point it i would recommend doing the following:

```
function postRequest(callback)
{
    var callbackFunc = callback||null;

    var xmlHttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { // For Mozilla, Safari, ...
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    { // For Internet Explorer
        var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlHttp.open('GET', 'effort.php', true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {       
            get_string(xmlHttp.responseText);

            if(callbackFunc){
               callbackFunc();
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function point_it(event)
{
    postRequest(dij);
}
```

this allows you to vary the callback that uses the array thats been populated by the post request and in a away that it always fires **after** that request cycle is complete.

Comment: @prodigy I am facing this kind of problem.If I call dij function from within postRequest...... it receives the correct data of the first three arrays of integers except the last one .... i.e. y[]. How can get through this .....

Comment: This is the only problem which I have been facing since the whole night ! i.e the value of the array elements of y[] gets changed in dij while I have correct access to the data in the other three arrays .

Comment: @user522003: then you need to rethink the flow of your functions and architecture :-) PErhps you should post another question that describes exactly what you are trying to implement in this recent flurry of questions... that way youll get suggestions for how to do it in terms of architecture, not just the nuts and bolts of the pieces.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` is **asynchronous**.

That means, it will return as soon as the request was **send**. If you now call `dij()` the request will still be **pending** and `get_string` wasn't called yet.

As soon as the requests completes, the **callback** will be called, and then execute `get_string`.

You need to leave `dij()` inside the callback too.

Visually:

- `postRequest` is made, sets the callback, but does **not** execute it, `postRequest` then returns
- the code after the call to `postRequest` executes
- some time passes...
- the `XMLHttpRequest` finally completes and the callback executes, which now calls `get_string`

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are not a good practice. It is better to combine your get_string and dij functions into one with your arrays as local variables inside the single function.